# Ejecutar una función al cerrar un modal

Tags: javascript, modal

Tengo el siguiente modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="TanqueBajo" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Tanque Bajo y Pozos</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="txtTanqueBajoInspeccionados">Inspeccionados:</label>
          <input id="txtTanqueBajoInspeccionados" name="txtTanqueBajoInspeccionados" type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Número de inspeccionados">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button id="btTanqueBajo" type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Que lo llamo al hacer clic el siguiente botón:

```
<button id="btTanqueBajo" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-block" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#TanqueBajo">Tanque Bajo y Pozo</button>
```

Deseo cambiar la clase del botón, después de cerrar el modal, para ello tengo la siguiente función:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#TanqueBajo').on('hidden.bs.modal', function(e) { document.getElementById("btTanqueBajo").className = 'btn btn-primary btn-block';});
});
```

Pero no me funciona. Podrían ayudarme indicándome que estoy haciendo mal o alguna otra alternativa de solución. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Probé tu código y si me funciona => [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QmJdrr), ¿Estás seguro que estás llamando a las librerías de javascript correspondientes?

Comment: Podrías también cambiar la clase del botón al momento de pulsar este, ej: `$('#btTanqueBajo').on('click'...`

Comment: Estimado @KacosPro, paree que es lo que indicas, podrías indicarme que librerías exactas son las que debería llamar? Estoy llamando al jquery y bootstrap, pero tal vez no sea las versiones correctas.

Comment: Muchas gracias @KacosPro, ya di con el error, tenías dos versiones JQuery jalando y se cruzaban, me quedé con una y quedó bien.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

espero te sriva

```js
var element = $('#btTanqueBajo');
$('#classA').text("Clase inicial : "+element.attr("class"));

$("#TanqueBajo").on('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
  element.attr("class", "btn btn-primary btn-block");
  $('#classN').text("Clase actual : "+element.attr("class"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<button id="btTanqueBajo" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-block" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#TanqueBajo">Tanque Bajo y Pozo</button>
<p id="classA"></p>
<p id="classN"></p>


<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="TanqueBajo" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Gracias @Hector Lara, efectivamente estaba llamando mal las librerías, tenía a dos versiones jquery jalando y parece que se cruzaban. Muchas gracias.

Comment: @AlcibiadesPalestini un placer ayudar hermano

Answer (score -1):

Otra solución podría ser cambiar la clase del botón al momento de pulsar este.

Ejemplo: Cambiar

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#TanqueBajo').on('hidden.bs.modal', function(e) { document.getElementById("btTanqueBajo").className = 'btn btn-primary btn-block';});
});
```

Por

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#btTanqueBajo').on('click', function(e) { document.getElementById("btTanqueBajo").className = 'btn btn-primary btn-block';});
});
```

Comment: El OP también solicitaba alguna otra alternativa de solución al problema, entonces porque calificar negativo la respuesta!!